# WebSpeechAPI to run on browser

Tags: javascript, html, webspeech-api

I'm working as a software developer trainee in an organisation and
I'm trying to achieve a webspeechApi code which can access browser..
suppose if I say 'open facebook' the browser should open facebook. I've tried using annyang but I don't wanna add any external libraries because of security reasons

```
<script>
    var message = document.querySelector('#message');

    var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition;
    var SpeechGrammarList = SpeechGrammarList || webkitSpeechGrammarList;

    var grammar = '#JSGF V1.0;'

    var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
    var speechRecognitionList = new SpeechGrammarList();
    speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1);
    recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;
    recognition.lang = 'en-US';
    recognition.interimResults = false;

    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
        var last = event.results.length - 1;
     
        var commands = {
            'open facebook' : open,
        }
            
        function openfacebook(){
            alert('opening facebook')
            console.log('open facebook');
            location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/';            
        }
    
    };

    recognition.onspeechend = function() {
        recognition.stop();
    };

    recognition.onerror = function(event) {
        message.textContent = 'Error occurred in recognition: ' + event.error;
    }        

    document.querySelector('#btnGiveCommand').addEventListener('click', function(){
        recognition.start();

    });

</script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: webspeechApi to access site

Comment: That is not a question. Do you have issues with the code you've posted?

Comment: yes..my code isn't working and i'm having a hard time to find why

Comment: You've to describe what you want your code to do, and what it does instead. If there are error message(s) in the console, please add those messages to the post too.

Comment: no error messages..when i run this code in browser it asks my permission to access microphone and when i give command 'open facebook' and i get no results

Comment: i've mentioned in the code as var command

Comment: i;ve defined a function and have given the location tooand still its not accessing

Comment: Add an `onnomatch` listener, maybe your command is not recognized.

Comment: and where should i add onmatch listener? sorry i'm a bit new to this

Comment: To `recognition` object.

Comment: as in to i have to replace onnomatch listener wherever i have used recognition?

Comment: like where i have to use onnomatch listener to my code? can u look at my code and tell me

Comment: can you check and run the code? i dont know whats wrong with it and i have a deadline of this week

Comment: hey did u check it?